# Ordering a list using another list. swap items based on second list

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have two lists where list A has some items and list B has the ordered values which can be used to re-arrange the list A.

list A = [X, A, Y, B, C, D, E, F],

List B = [D, B, A]

The result I need to get :

result: [X, **D**, Y, **B**, C, **A**, E, F].

As you can see the as per the elements mentioned in the list B, List A's elements are swapped and ordered.

Can we use java comparator to achieve this ? or is there any fastest way ?

in Actual scenario,

List A contains objects of A and list B contains the mongoIds of that objects.

```
class A{

 string mongoId;
 string name;

//getters and setters

}
```

Comment: For the actual scenario, list B is still only a sub-set of the objects in list A as in your first example?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson , yes a subset of ids because list B is not holding objects.

Comment: Will your List B will always be subset of List A. Or could it be the case that List A can have only subset of List B?

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be a case for a comparator. My idea would be to build a map that will hold the values of your list B as keys and their indices in list A as values. Then going through that map you can make the appropriate switches in the List A

Comment: Thanks, in that case if we build a map wth keys n indices, then how would we identify to swap A with D ?

Comment: You iterate through your map and see if the elements need switching according to your List B.

Comment: eg: list A= [X, A, Y, B, C, D, E, F] , List B = [D, B, X]

result: [D, A, Y, B, C, X, E, F]

sample like this ?

Comment: Your last comment is a short repetition of your question. There is no additional question. I am bot sure what is it that you are asking in your comment that is different from your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try below function.

Here, i am assuming that List B will be a complete subset of List A. If that is not the case, you need to filter the List B such that all those `MongoIds` are removed which are not present in List A.

**Explanation**: Iterate the List `A` and check if the current element is part of List `B`. If yes, get the first element of list `B` and find its index in List `A`. Lets say you find it at index `b0`. After that you can replace the current element of List `A` under iteration with the element at `a[b0]`. After that you can repeat this exercise for all the other elements of List `A` for which you find its `mongoId` in List `B`.

Note: Every time you find the `mongoId` in List `B`, you will have to increment the `swap` count to get the next element of List `B`.

```
public static List<A> mySort(List<A> a, List <String> b){
  final int[] swap=new int[1];
  swap[0]=0;
  List<A> newl = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++){
    if(b.contains(a.get(i).getMongoId())){
      A temp= a.stream().filter(f->f.getMongoId().equals(b.get(swap[0]))).findFirst().get();
      int index=a.indexOf(temp); 
      newl.add(a.get(index));
      swap[0]++;
    } else {
      newl.add(a.get(i));
    }
  }
  return newl;
}
```

I have tested this code also. You can check it [here](https://onlinegdb.com/BJf_DlSkS).

Comment: What should I explain in this? All these lines are self explanatory.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Done. Let me know if you feel the need of some additional explanation.